# JQuery DataTables - Catch 'ajax' response

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I have an web-application that uses JQuery DataTables. It uses the `ajax` parameter for requesting and inserting JSON data into the table.

However, at the top of the requested `.php` file it is checked whether the user is logged in. If this check fails it echoes a JSON notice.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || $_SESSION['logged'] !== true) {
        $array = array(utf8_encode('logged')=>utf8_encode('false'));
        echo json_encode($array);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

---

```
table = $('#active-issues').DataTable({
        "scrollY": pixels,
        "dom": '<"top"if>rt<"bottom"><"clear">',
        "paging": false,
        "responsive":true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "ajax": {
            "data": function(){
                $('#active-issues').DataTable().ajax.url(
                    "php/get_issues.php"
                    + "?id=" + id
                    + "&customer_id=" + customerid
                );
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { responsivePriority: 1 },
            { responsivePriority: 2 },
            { responsivePriority: 4 },
            { responsivePriority: 3 },
            { responsivePriority: 5 },
            { responsivePriority: 6 },
            { responsivePriority: 7 }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "type": "alt-string", targets: 5},
            { "type": "alt-string", targets: 6},
        ]
    });
```

---

```
table.ajax.reload(null, false);
```

Is it possible to catch the response given to JQuery DataTables? So that I can check whether result is `{ logged: "false" }` and act accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a while and the help of 'allan' from datatables forums. But the problem is finally solved.

via `dataSrc` it's possible to manipulate the ajax result before it is printed in the table, I, however, used it to check whether the result contains `logged` and whether it equals to `false` and act accordingly if it does:

```
"ajax": {
    "data": function(){
        $('#active-issues').DataTable().ajax.url(
            "php/get_issues.php?id=" + id + "&customer_id=" + customerid
        );
    },
    "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
        if(typeof json['logged'] != "undefined") {
            if (json['logged'] == 'false') {
                location.replace('php/logout.php');
            }
        }
        return json.aaData;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done if you do your ajax cal externally i.e perform an independent ajax request to obtain the response and the identify if the response contains
{ logged: "false" } and the populate the data to the data table accordingly.